# Foreign Key - get values

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I have created the following models. Many Accounts belong to one Computer.

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)



class Accounts(models.Model):
    computer = models.ForeignKey(Computer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_name_accounts')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

I now want to create a Form where i can choose one user from a dropdown-list of all users that belong to a Computer

```
class ComputerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        exclude = ['name',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComputerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Computer.related_name_accounts.all())
```

But i get an error

> 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

How do i have to adjust the queryset in `__init__` to display all users of a computer?

**Edit:**

```
>>> x = Computer.objects.filter(pk=3).get()
>>> x.related_name_accounts.all()
```

I would somehow need to pass the dynamic pk to the ModelForm?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you used a capital `C` in `Computer.related_name_accounts.all()`. This doesn't make sense, because the `Computer` model doesn't have related fields - it's *instances* do.

This line of code would work:

```
computer = Computer.objects.get(id=1)
computer.related_name_accounts.all()
```

But the issue is, I am not sure what you mean by `...of all users that belong to a Computer`, since you don't have a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOne` relationship between `User` and `Computer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of your model to the form like this:

```
x = Computer.objects.get(pk=3)
form = ComputerForm(instace=x)
```

And access it through `self.instance` in the form methods:

```
class ComputerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        exclude = ['name',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ComputerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user']=forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=self.instance.related_name_accounts.all()
        )
```